# Reading from a BluetoothGattCharacteristic is failing

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-ble

Im trying to read the value stored in a `BluetoothGattCharacteristic`. The following is my `BluetoothGattCallback` code, where most of the action takes place:

```
 private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback =
            new BluetoothGattCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status,
                                                    int newState) {
                    if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
                        Log.i(TAG, "Getting services....");
                        gatt.discoverServices();
                    } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
                    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                        BluetoothGattService serv = gatt.getService(Constants.MY_UUID);
                        if (serv != null) {
                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = serv.getCharacteristic(Constants.ANOTHER_UUID);
                            boolean res = gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
                            if (res) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "res was true");
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "res was false");
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                                 BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                                 int status) {
                    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Succesfully read characteristic: " + characteristic.getValue().toString());
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Characteristic read not successful");
                    }
                }
            };
```

So to read from the characteristic, i'm attempting to use the `gatt.readCharacteristic()` method, which takes a characteristic and returns a boolean indicating a successful operation or not. Here, this method is returning `false` (printing "res was false"), indicating it failed.

There is no error message being printed. What is the proper way to read a characteristic? Why would this method be returning `false`?

**EDIT:**
As suggested by Inferno, went ahead and downloaded the needed sources and then set a breakpoint in the `BluetoothGatt` `readCharacteristic()` method:

Here is the `readCharacteristic()` method in android-23..\BluetoothGatt

```
public boolean readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        if ((characteristic.getProperties() &
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) == 0) return false;
```

`(characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ)` is returning 0 so `false` is being immediately returned. Now according to the debugger `characteristic.getProperties()` is returning a value of `8`, while `BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ` has a static int value of `0x02`.

As I understand, `0x08 & 0x02` == 0. Since the `PROPERTY_READ` is a hardcoded value, I assume something is wrong with the value returned from `characteristic.getProperties()`. What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Is the callback `onCharacteristicRead()` happening even when `gatt.readCharacteristic()` returns `false`?

Comment: No, it does not get called.

Comment: I'll update my answer, give me a second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the proper way to read a characteristic?

First of all, you call `gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic)` from inside of the `onServicesDiscovered()` callback, which is alright. I can't see any serious flaws in your code.

What you could add in `onConnectionStateChange()` is an additional check *before* you verify `newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED`:

```
if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) { ...
```

> Why would this method be returning false?

I checked the android source of `BluetoothGatt` [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.java) and it turns out, the return value of `false` is returned in many different cases as you can see in the code below:

```
public boolean readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    if ((characteristic.getProperties() &
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) == 0) return false;

    if (VDBG) Log.d(TAG, "readCharacteristic() - uuid: " + characteristic.getUuid());
    if (mService == null || mClientIf == 0) return false;

    BluetoothGattService service = characteristic.getService();
    if (service == null) return false;

    BluetoothDevice device = service.getDevice();
    if (device == null) return false;

    synchronized(mDeviceBusy) {
        if (mDeviceBusy) return false;
        mDeviceBusy = true;
    }

    try {
        mService.readCharacteristic(mClientIf, device.getAddress(),
            characteristic.getInstanceId(), AUTHENTICATION_NONE);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"",e);
        mDeviceBusy = false;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

So what I recommend you to do is, start the debugger in Android Studio and set a breakpoint inside the `readCharacteristic()` method (in `BluetoothGatt.java`) and *carefully* step through the code to see where `false` gets returned. That way you will hopefully be able to localize the issue. Besides that, anything else would be wild guessing.

Of course you need to have the sources downloaded to be able to view `BluetoothGatt.java`. But Android Studio will give you a small yellow bar at the top of the editor which asks you if you want to download and install. Just do it and restart Android Studio after the download is complete. Then you should be able to set a breakpoint in `BluetoothGatt.java`.

UPDATE:

> As I understand, 0x08 & 0x02 == 0. Since the PROPERTY_READ is a
>   hardcoded value, I assume something is wrong with the value returned
>   from characteristic.getProperties(). What could be going wrong here?

According to BLUETOOTH SPECIFICATION Version 4.2 [Vol 3, Part G] page 533, the value of `0x8` which is returned by `characteristic.getProperties()` means, that your characteristic has *write only* permissions. Not a surprise that all reading attempts fail. In other words: your bluetooth device does not allow you to read that particular characteristic.

Quote from the specification:

> The Characteristic Properties bit field determines how the Characteristic Value
>   can be used, or how the characteristic descriptors (see Section 3.3.3) can be
>   accessed.

Comment: I opened up the `readCharacteristic()` method and downloaded the source, but for some odd reason it doesn't seem to have detected the newly downloaded source, so I am unable to set a proper breakpoint.

Comment: Yes I had the same problem with Android Studio. I had to close and reopen the program and then it showed the full sources instead of the method stubs only.

Comment: Yea, I've restarted it a few times already, will try a few other things.

Comment: I'm on version 2.2. Double check if it really downloaded/installed the sources correctly. You could also try File --> Invalidate Caches.

Comment: Yep, I had restarted and invalidated the cache. Ended up upgrading Android Studio from 2.1.x to 2.2, and can now properly read the sources, and set the breakpoint. I've updated my question with some details.

Comment: Ok, I've read your update. Is this permissions value hardcoded into the device or is there a way I can set it to be readable? My `characteristics` object has a `.getPermissions()` method, but nothing suggesting a way to set permissions.

Comment: If you mean the value of `0x8` for that particular characteristic, yes. It is hardcoded in your device. Your bluetooth device may have more characteristics, which are readable too. You can get them all by calling `getCharacteristics()` for example. Then you can check in the debugger what properties they have (e.g. read/write/notify/...)

Comment: Yes, the `.getProperties()` method is returning 8 (0x08). The specification I was given suggested this characteristic was to be read from, will have to ask my client about it then. I'll be sure to take a look at the other characteristics. I'll go ahead and accept your answer for now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You obtained your characteristic by `serv.getCharacteristic(Constants.ANOTHER_UUID)`. Just make sure you use the UUID of a characteristic that is readable.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to read data back from a cow brush scratcher that had BLE chip. 
It was under a read characteristic on a BLE module.
The data was coming back in hex i.e. 0x00 for BRUSH_OFF  &   0x01 for BRUSH_ON

I was trying to read in this data in my android app and it kept coming back as blank.

Problem is 0x00 = NUll in ascii     and     0x01 = SOH  ascii  it cannot be displayed on the screen.

0x30 = 0 in ascii    0x31 = 1 in ascii

Maybe you have escape characters coming back in hex and they cannot be read.

I spent months trying to figure out why i couldn't read back the values.
Hope this might help you.