# Cannot read BLE Characterstic from Android

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Important to note, I am using Xamarin to develop Cross-platform apps. For bluetooth I have to develop platform specfic, therefore the following code is all part of the android library, but coded in C#, since that is the language of xamarin. It is relatively easy to understand, even if you do not know C# or Xamarin.

My problem is very similiar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736475/reading-from-a-bluetoothgattcharacteristic-is-failing) one, with the difference that I am completely sure that I have permission to read, since it does work from iOS.

I work with a BLE heart rate monitor. I connect to it, then set notifications for the heart rate characteristic and then read it. From iOS this works perfectly fine. From android however it tells me I do not have the permissions to read the characterstic. This is obviously wrong, since it works from iOS. What could be the cause here? Do I maybe need to reload the permissions after connecting to a device? I didn't find a function for that.

This is the code I use to connect to the device.

```
bleGatt = device.ConnectGatt(Android.App.Application.Context, false, new MyGattCallback(this));
```

Then in the connection status changed I start service discovery. The `handleConnectionSuccess()` and `handleDisconnect()` go back to the UI to show the progress to the user.

```
public override void OnConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, 
            [GeneratedEnum] GattStatus status, [GeneratedEnum] ProfileState newState)
{
    switch(newState)
    {
    case ProfileState.Connected:
        reference.handleConnectionSuccess();
        gatt.DiscoverServices();
        break;
    case ProfileState.Disconnected:
        reference.handleDisconnect();
        break;
    }
}

public override void OnServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, [GeneratedEnum] GattStatus status)
{
    if (status == GattStatus.Success) {
        BluetoothGattService service = bleGatt.GetService(UUID.FromString("CDEACB80-5235-4C07-8846-93A37EE6B86D"));
        if (service == null)
            return;
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = service.GetCharacteristic(UUID.FromString("CDEACB80-5235-4C07-8846-93A37EE6B86D"));
        bleGatt.SetCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
        bool readable = ((characteristic.Permissions & GattPermission.Read) != 0);
        Debug.WriteLine("Characteristic is readable: " + readable + " Permissions: " + characteristic.Permissions);
    } else 
        Debug.WriteLine("Service Discovery ended with not success status: " + status);
    }
}
```

Here I always get the output: `Characteristic is readable: False Permissions: 0`
Later on `gatt.ReadCharacteristic()` returns false, which according to the sources of android is because I do not have the permissions to read. (see [in the referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736475/reading-from-a-bluetoothgattcharacteristic-is-failing))

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related but why do you have the same uuid for both the service and the characteristic?

Comment: That is correct, I use it in iOS as well just checked. But also was wondering^^,

Comment: Not sure why this is happening, but an aside - are you using the BLE standard Heart Rate Measurement characteristic? https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml

Comment: Also, do you need to explicitly set the Gatt Descriptor? Around Line 246 ... https://github.com/RobotPajamas/Blueteeth/blob/feature/kotlin/blueteeth/src/main/java/com/robotpajamas/blueteeth/BlueteethDevice.kt

Comment: Would this happen to be the omron hem-6321T? I'm having a similar issue with a device with the exact same UUID.

Comment: Permissions are set on a platform by platform basis. IOW you need to set a NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription value in the Info.plist for iOS in order for your app to interact with a bluetooth peripheral. Likewise you have to set the a bluetooth permission for Android in the AndroidManifest.xml file. There are three bluetooth permissions for Android: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, even thought I am not allowed to read from the characteristic the value automatically updates without `readCharacteristics()` needing to be called and I can just call `getValue()` and it works.